# Select a list items that id's difference in one number Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of "select elements" (dropdownboxes) in a page. Their ids are similar and have one difference - one number. For example:

```
Step2_Visits_0__CountryCode
Step2_Visits_1__CountryCode
Step2_Visits_2__CountryCode
Step2_Visits_3__CountryCode
Step2_Visits_4__CountryCode
```

How to select them? I don't want to enumerate them in selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the [begins-with selector (`^=`) and ends-with selector (`$=`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/):

```
$('[id^="Step2_Visits_"][id$="__CountryCode"]')
```

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/8pc2u/).

This selects any element whose ID begins with "Step2_Visits_" and ends with "__CountryCode".

> E[foo^="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"
>   E[foo$="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value ends exactly with the string "bar"

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider adding class to those elements and selecting this class.